What would allow/block python from receiving a socket connection with an unprivileged user
I'm on ubuntu 18 systems with unknown prior setups.
Running as an unprivileged user the following python code:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(5)

I get no errors, it binds.  I can check in the OS and it is listening.  nmap shows the port as well.  However if I try sending data to it, nothing is received.  The same code on another system works fine.  However if I run the code as root, I do receive data.  I'm using port 12345 (above the 1024 limit on the system)
Therefore, something on the systems are configured differently to allow this.  I'm not sure what.
Firewalls are disabled.

You don't indicate what port you're binding to but you might look at sysctl net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start on the two systems.

Please edit the question and add the info of the version of Ubuntu you are using.

I picked 12345 and the setting on both systems are 1024.  Edited to add version.

How have you verified that firewall is disabled? Have you verified that data is received at the network level using wireshark?

Did you test to make sure local traffic on that listen port works from the same system?

Yes, I already said that the firewall is disabled.  Also, it works when I run as root so I know data can be received.  It's only when I don't run as root (eventhough it works on other systems without running as root)  So I'm assuming it is some setting restricted to root.  But I don't know what settings would affect network in that way.  Also, if I run something like iperf on the same port (not as root) it works fine
